# unable to get proper result using threads

Tags: java

Suppose I have three arrays with different length. 
I want to sort these three arrays with three different threads.

I wrote below code for this. So is it write or there is something happening wrong.
Sometimes it is giving me correct result and sometimes the values of arrays are merging with other array's values:

**I added syncronized to display method, again getting incorrect result.**

```
public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {
    private int[] arr;
    private String[] s_arr;

    public ThreadDemo(int arr[]) {
        this.arr=arr;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getSorted(arr);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getSorted(int[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (arr.length-1) - i; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        display(arr);
    }

public static void display(int[] a){

        for(int i:a)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        System.out.println();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[]={8,25,9,12,13,17,1};
        int arr2[]={38,2,19,12,3,17,16};
        int arr3[]={3,22,9,1,34,17,86};
        ThreadDemo demo1=new ThreadDemo(arr1);
        Thread t1=new Thread(demo1);
        ThreadDemo demo2=new ThreadDemo(arr2);
        Thread t2=new Thread(demo2);
        ThreadDemo demo3=new ThreadDemo(arr3);
        Thread t3=new Thread(demo3);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Output #1: here values are mixing.

```
1 8 9 12 13 17 25
2 3 12 16 17 1 3 9 17 22 34 86 
19 38
```

Output #2: correct

```
1 8 9 12 13 17 25 
2 3 12 16 17 19 38 
1 3 9 17 22 34 86
```

output #3: incorrect

```
1 8 9 12 13 17 25 
2 1 3 3 12 9 16 17 17 22 19 38 
34 86 

public static synchronized void display(int[] a){

        for(int i:a)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Comment: @DJClayworth I think you are right, perhaps just make that an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Your use of `synchronized` is not particularly good. In fact, since the monitors are different, it's useless. Synchronize on a shared monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays are probably in the correct order. But the printed results are being interleaved because the prints are happening on different threads.

Sort the arrays on each thread and then print all the results once all threads have finished.

Comment: will you please write a small code for this, that you are telling to call result.

Comment: @Musaddique You can look up how to wait for a thread to be finished. Do that on all three threads, then call 'display' on each of the three arrays, in the 'main' method.